# Fluentd merge join plugin

Tags: fluentd

We have different entities submitted separately and we would like to merge them.

Suppose that we have a user registration with multiple steps. Each steps firing an event.

- step1
- step2
- step3

each event has a session id that is common. We would like on `step3` enrich the data with `step1` and `step2`.

How can we handle such a merge operation in Fluentd?